# SELECT: math and comparing mulitple tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that are similar in nature except for the increase in values over time. I need to pull data and manipulate with math functions.

Example 1   earlier time

```
Name           Points
person1        500
person1        200
person2        300
person3        200
```

some have duplicate name entries with different point values

Example 2 - later time

```
Name           Points
person1        600
person1        205
person2        350
person3        200
person4        45
```

new person added later

the final result should calculate

```
Name       Combined Difference (laterearlier)  Weighted Total
person1    805700=105                          105X3000/200=1575
person2    350300=50                           50X3000/200=750
person3    200200=0                            0X3000/200=0
person4    45null=45                           45X3000/200=675
```

3000 is a constant
200 is combined total of differences

This works for 2 columns on 1 table

```
SELECT address, SUM(totalpts) AS DAY2
FROM table1
GROUP BY address
ORDER BY address
```

However when I try a JOIN it does not calculate properly

```
SELECT a1.address, SUM(a1.totalpts), a2.totalpts
FROM table1 AS a1
   LEFT JOIN table2 AS a2 ON a1.address = a2.address
GROUP BY a1.address
ORDER BY a1.address
```

I am comparing two specific dates or points in time. each date represents its own table - so there are two tables, identical structure, different data

Comment: And what is your question? Sounds like you need a `SUM` and `GROUP BY` clause. Have you tried to write anything else?

Comment: Are you comparing only two points in time at once, or are "earlier" and "later" two ranges of dates/times?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I can get one or the other column to calculate, but not both at the same time. it is phpmyadmin / mysql platform

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` creates more rows, then `SUM` adds up the extra rows.

Maybe this gives you what you want:

```
SELECT  a1.address,
        SUM(a1.totalpts),
        ( SELECT totalpts FROM table2 WHERE address = a1.address ) AS at_pts
    FROM table1 AS a1
    GROUP BY a1.address
    ORDER BY a1.address
```